# NestJS Module not found: Error when trying to resolve enums in typescript

Tags: typescript, webpack, import, enums, nestjs

I have a nestjs project with typescript setup something like this ( obviously I removed the things which were not related to the question )

[image]

What I am trying to do is the following

In the file data-basic-input.dto.ts I am importing the data-type.enum.ts in the following way

```
`import { DataType } from '@shortcut/constants/enums/data-type.enum';`
```

The data-type.enum.ts contains the following code

```
`export enum DataType {
  L1 = 101,
  H1 = 201,
  L2 = 102,
  H2 = 202,
  L3 = 103,
  H3 = 203,
  L4 = 104,
}`
```

And when I try to build and run the project I have the following error

`ERROR in ./src/datas/dtos/data-basic-input.dto.ts 24:147-251 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './c:/Projects/project/libs/constants/src/enums/data-type' in 'c:\Projects\project\src\alarms\dtos' @ ./src/alarms/dtos/data-input.dto.ts 17:32-66 ....`

So, when I am trying to import an enum it does not found it .... other imports from the same folder work properly

**The interesting thing is that this error only happens on Windows, I tried on Mac or Linux and everything works ok**

Additional information:

The nest-cli.json looks in the following way

[image]

In order to use that type of import I have this setup in my tsconfig.json

[image]

I have installed the following versions

- Typescript - 4.9.4
- Webpack - 5.75.0
- ts-loader - 9.4.2
- tsconfig-paths - 4.1.1

Any idea that could point me in the right direction would be welcomed
Thanks a lot

Things that I tried but did not work

- renaming the file without enum at the end
- trying to export const enum DataType, so adding a const besides the enum
- tried to debug by setting "traceResolution": true in the tsconfig.json but from reading the stack I see that the file is being found and loaded properly
- all kinds of different tsconfig or webpack options

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I am having the same problem in my typecript files.

Answer (score 0):

To get enums to work in my dto files I have had good luck as follows:

```
// create-user.dto

import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';

import {
  IsEnum,
} from 'class-validator';

import { RoleEnum } from '../enum/role.enum';

export class CreateUserDto {

  ...

  @ApiProperty({
    description: "The user's role.",
    example: 'EMPLOYEE',
  })
  @IsEnum(RoleEnum)
  @IsNotEmpty()
  role: RoleEnum;
}
```

As you can see from my import, I have created my `role.enum` file:

```
// role.enum

export enum RoleEnum {
  ADMINISTRATOR = 'ADMINISTRATOR',
  MANAGER = 'MANAGER',
  EMPLOYEE = 'EMPLOYEE',
  GUEST = 'GUEST',
}
```

For what it's worth, here is what my `user.entity` file looks like for that:

```
// user.entity

...

@Column({
    type: 'enum',
    enum: RoleEnum,
  })
  role: RoleEnum;
```

Following this method, I am able to leverage the built-in validators for to check for a legit enum value. If something like `WORKER` is passed in, the server will return a 400 error.

Comment: Hello, Damon. Thanks for your answer. Indeed, if you use relative imports it will work properly and those too are working in my project. On the other hand, I would prefer to make them work using non-relative imports, ie. import { TestEnum } from '@TestModule/constants/test-enum.ts' or something in this form

Answer (score 0):

Had exactly the same problem with my local package named `@node-operations/shared`. My project could be built but could not start with same error. Seems that nest swagger plugin needs to check types in runtime and wants them to be near project. I made a little hack:

1. Added to tsconfig.json :

```json
  "paths": {
    "@node-operations/shared": [ "../shared" ]
  },
  "include": [
    "../shared", "./src"
  ]
```

2. Changed nest-cli.json from

```json
  "sourceRoot": "src",
```

to

```json
  "sourceRoot": "project-name/src",
```

and after that swagger finally can find everything on startup because now my library resides into nest app's `dist` folder.

That's really unexpected that it only happens with enums, only with swagger module enabled and only in dev mode. I made an [issue on github](https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/issues/2265) but I doubt that someone will look through it.